# C# Windows Service with multiple timers from file

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have multiple "jobs" with timers in a file.
I want to use all of them but when i start the service i see that only the last timer in the configuration is working
How can i do have multiple timers created based on a List that can change over time (yes i can restart the service when i change the list but i don't want to write a timer foreach

Here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using InserterService.Dao;
namespace InserterService
{

public partial class InserterService : ServiceBase
{
    public InserterService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    class CustomTimer : System.Timers.Timer
    {
        public Configurazione configurazione;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //** CARICA CONFIGURAZIONI **//


        // PER OGNI CONFIGURAZIONE DEFINISCO IL TIMER
        List<Configurazione> Configurazioni = new List<Configurazione>();
        Configurazioni = ModulReader.GetModulCopyDirectory();
        int i = 0;
       foreach (var item in Configurazioni )
        {
            i++;
            string data = string.Format("CONFIGURAZIONE {0}",i.ToString());
            string folder = @"C:\temp\OUT\";
            // Filename  
            string fileName = "Test.txt";
            // Fullpath. You can direct hardcode it if you like.  
            string fullPath = folder + fileName;
            File.AppendAllText(fullPath, data);
            var timer = new CustomTimer
            {
                Interval = Int32.Parse(item.TIMER.Trim()),
                configurazione = item
            };
            
            timer.Elapsed += Lavorazione;
            timer.Start();
        }

    }



    public void Lavorazione(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Configurazione configurazione = ((CustomTimer)sender).configurazione;

        string data = configurazione.DATA;
        string folder = @"C:\temp\OUT\";
        // Filename  
        string fileName = "Test.txt";
        // Fullpath. You can direct hardcode it if you like.  
        string fullPath = folder + fileName;
        File.AppendAllText(fullPath, data);

    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you can use "quartz scheduler" in the windows service.

Comment: *'i see that only the last timer in the configuration is working*' - how do you see that? What is not working as expected? You don't have any exception handling in `Lavorazione`.